# Media queries leaking across frames

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, media-queries

Here's some HTML:

```
<iframe src="test.html" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></iframe>
<iframe src="test.html" style="width: 800px; height: 100px;"></iframe>
```

The `test.html` page contains some CSS from an external file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

And the stylesheet has:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {background-color: red;}
}
```

The above is simplified, but enough to demonstrate the issue: Both pages are red, despite one of them clearly being wider than the other. [Demonstration page](http://adamhaskell.net/misc/ifrtest/)

What gives?

(Note: Tested in IE and Chrome - Chrome was fine, with one frame red and the other white.)

Comment: which IE are you testing this on? For sure it won't work in IE8 or less because media queries aren't supported in previous version of IE8. It's only supported in IE9

Comment: Ya think? If it were IE8 or less both the iframes would be white, not red.

Comment: Not necessarily. I just tried on IE 7 and both pages are white.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316247/media-queries-fail-inside-ie9-iframe), Internet Explorer 9 supports CSS3 media queries, but not within frames when the CSS containing the media query is in an external file, so you should put your media query in the head of the `test.html` page. Previous IE versions don't support media queries natively, but you could use a javascript library (see [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) or [css3-mediaqueries-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)) to overcome this problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! This is extemely hard to find and just putting the media query into the main body of the html instead of the stylesheet makes it work perfectly on IE9. (Note this bug is IE9 Win7 only - not a problem on Vista or any other IE version).

Comment: If this isn't practical for you to do, you can let IE9 see each CSS file as a separate entity by changing the URL to each - add a unique URL parameter to the shared CSS file with the media queries. E.g., main frame loads site.css, iframe loads site.css?frame=1. Same effect.

Comment: @sync: awesome solution. I added #iefix to the frame's css and now it works properly

Answer (score -1):

You can do the job by using jquery with the following script :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(document).width() < 600) {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Really? And what if I: a) Utterly despise jQuery? b) Don't want a JavaScript solution to this CSS problem? c) Want to resize the window?

Comment: Well... I agree that using jQuery is not the cleanest way to do a CSS job. But I'm not even sure if it's possible to do that on IE9 older versions. Also, you can adjust the script to re-compute background when the window is resized :) If you find an other solution, don't forget to write it here. I'm curious about that.

Comment: Well, yes, in this example a JS solution would work. However this is a much simplified example. There may an arbitrary number of elements that need adjusting, and cascading would still need to work right.