# Liferay 6.2 - IE 9 open a pop-up turns parent page to responsive design

Tags: responsive-design, popup, internet-explorer-9, liferay, alloy-ui

I am on Liferay 6.2 and my web browser is IE 9. 
I have a pop-up opened by an AUI function from a parent page with a simple button.

```
AUI().use( 'aui-io-deprecated','aui-modal', function(A){

     Liferay.Util.openWindow(
         {
             dialog: {
             centered: true,
             resizable: false,
             destroyOnClose: true,
             cache: false,
             width: 600,
             height: 500,
             modal: true
            },

});
```

When the pop-up is opened, my parent page turns to responsive design...
The only way to come back in a normal page is to reload the entire page.
This problem is not happening in other browsers (IE 8, Firefox,...)

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thank you all.

Comment: This is a know issue with IE9. IE9 has a bug with media queries and iframes. We have a ticket for it, but it's currently not under development, as all solutions have negative performance impacts on the Portal's caching mechanisms. https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-47713

Comment: Related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416610/media-queries-leaking-across-frames
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316247/media-queries-fail-inside-ie9-iframe

Comment: Thank you all for your comments