# IE 11 selects wrong css media until window resize

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have CSS with the next media `@media screen and (max-width: 640px)`
IE 11 uses CSS inside this `@media` even though the window width is much more than 640px. If I manually resize the window (in any direction, increase or decrease) then IE 11 picks up the correct CSS(outside of this `@media`) and everything looks good. In other browsers, everything works as expected.

How this problem can be tackled?
Probably I can emulate window resize somehow?
Thank you in advance.

UPD: Also if devtools are enabled everything is working as it should...

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Or if that turns out not possible, at least a link to a website where this happens. A Q&D test shows that IE1 behaves as expected.

Comment: Looks like your css code has some issue in it if you try to provide a sample code than we can try to check the issue and try to provide a suggestion that can help to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724919/1079966